# How to CREATE TABLE using sql/VBA in excel with ADO

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to erase table content and replace it with new content in an excel sheet.

The code doesn't raise any errors however everytime I run it, **it inserts some blanck cells before the source table**.

The 'base.xlsx' table sheet looks like this :

[image: base]

If target.xlsx is void before running the code I get what I want however if I run it again I get this :

[image: target]

Here is the code :

```
Sub SQLQUERY()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim QUERY_SQL As String
    Dim ExcelCn As ADODB.Connection

    SourcePath = "C:\Path\to\base.xlsx"
    TargetPath = "C:\Path\to\target.xlsx"

    CHAINE_HDR = "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] "

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

    STRCONNECTION = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & SourcePath & "';" & _
    "Mode=Read;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;"";"

    Colonnes = "[Col#1], Col2"

    QUERY_SQL = _
    "SELECT " & Colonnes & " FROM [base$] " & _
    "IN '" & SourcePath & "' " & CHAINE_HDR

    MsgBox (QUERY_SQL)

    Cn.Open STRCONNECTION

    Set ExcelCn = New ADODB.Connection
    ExcelCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & TargetPath & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""

    ExcelCn.Execute "DROP TABLE [sheet$]"

    ExcelCn.Execute "CREATE TABLE [sheet$] ([C1] Float, [C2] Float, [C3] Float)"

    Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO [sheet$] (C1, C3) IN '" & TargetPath & "' 'Excel 12.0;' " & QUERY_SQL

    '--- Fermeture connexion ---

    Cn.Close
    ExcelCn.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I discovered what's going on with the code. When `Drop Table` is executed Excel keep the "active range" and thus INSERT INTO will insert data after the active range.

To counter this we need to specify a range with the table name :

```
ExcelCn.Execute "DROP TABLE [sheet$]"

ExcelCn.Execute "CREATE TABLE [sheet$] ([C1] Float, [C2] Float, [C3] Float)"

Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO [sheet$A1:ZZ1] (C1, C3) IN '" & TargetPath & "' 'Excel 12.0;' " & QUERY_SQL

'--- Fermeture connexion ---
```

Note the **[sheet$A1:ZZ1]** in the sql statement.